# hibernate inner select in from clause

Tags: hibernate, select, hql, criteria

I'd like to know if it's possible to specify a select clause in a from clause something like

```
select count(*) as Y, this_.NAME as A, sel2.C
from TABLE1 this_, 
    (select count(*) as C from 
        (select this_.NAME, this_.SEX 
        from TABLE1 this_ group by this_.NAME, this_.SEX) sel1
    ) sel2
group by this_.NAME, sel2.C;
```

I need a query like this in order to have the count number as an extra column in the outer query.
I can't find out how to specify a select statement in a from, neither with hql nor with criteria.

Thank you.

Luca

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your query? What is your model and what you are looking for. The query seems to be nonsense for me...

Answer (score 14):

According to Hibernate documentation HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses:

[Hibernate Community Documentation, Chapter 16. HQL - 16.3. Subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries)